# Print a ticket from apache flex

Tags: apache-flex

I want to print a ticket (10*5) cm on a labels printer from apache flex, i used this code

```
            var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
            printJob.start();
            groupLabel.width=378;
            groupLabel.height=188;
            printJob.addObject(groupLabel, FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH); 
            printJob.send();
```

but in print preview from chrome or if i print it not set the page size to the detected and assume it a A4 page, when i print on the labels printer it uses about 5 labels in one print job.
how can i set the page size or is there any another way or component to do this in flex?

Comment: printJob.pageWidth and printJob.pageHeight ?

Comment: these properties are read only.

Comment: Oh right :) Setting margins might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642008/how-to-dynamically-set-print-page-margins-in-flash-cs3